# C++, Error in Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I assigned array

```
char words[100][100];
```

Now I want to save a word and its pos in the line.
Say line has "hi Iam a programmer". Now I want to save

```
string word;

while(line){
//called a function to get the word and position.
words[word]["pos"] = pos;
}
```

I have split the `words` and saved in the string `word`, but when I try to save I get error.

```
"No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'char[100][100]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stay away from raw fxed size arrays, and use std::map< int, std::string >

Comment: You seem to want a combination of `std::vector` and `std::map`.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you'll need to learn C++ more systematically to use it. I suggest you find some introductory books or online tutorials. To do this you'd probably want to use `std::cin`, `getline`, `std::string`s, string iterators, `isspace()`, `std::map`... too much to learn totally ad-hoc and get right.  People telling you to use a `map` aren't helping you get the right stuff into it.

Comment: By the way, why `"pos"`? Are you really after `words[word][pos] = pos;`?

Comment: If I remove the size it gives me an error "Defination of array type needs an explicit size or an initializer.

Comment: well actually array goes something like this array[variable][fixed text "pos"] and stores the value of pos.

Comment: @TonyDelroy - You are right I need to learn it can you please tell me where I can find it. I learnt c++ from youtube.

Comment: @user1579911: you could try the stackoverflow C++ tag page - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info - it has lots of good links, one to a book list.  A little bit of well written introduction and a day's reading and playing with a compiler can get you off to a flying start.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `array` as a `map`. You can't use strings as array index. The structure you need is `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> >`

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> > m;
m["foo"]["bar"] = 10;
```

Comment: I tried your method but it says "no tamplate named map found in namespace std...." Do I have to include some file to get it work?

Comment: @user1579911: yes, `include <map>`

Answer (score 0):

`char[100][100]` is a multidimensional array of single characters, which can be used to store fixed-length strings.  It can be indexed using *integer* variables, not strings.

It looks like you want to use `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> >` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a string as an index in C++ arrays. What you need is a map:

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<string, int> > words;
```

Then you have to:

```
words[word]["pos"] = pos;
```

But, what other data would you be saving other than `pos`? If not, then why do you want to make it a 2 dimensional data structure? Can't you just:

```
positions[word] = pos;
```

Where `positions` is of type `std::map<std::string, int>`.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by *Mike*, not using pointers anymore.

Comment: Consider it my honest mistake; Fixed and added note.

Comment: Yes I am planning to save one more data. words[word]["pos"] = pos;
words[word]["count"] = count;  I tried your method but it says "no tamplate named map found in namespace std...." Do I have to include some file to get it work?

Comment: Yes, you need to include `map`: #include <map>